# HTML5 tags not working at all in firefox 3.6.3

Tags: html

Okay, so I'm trying to get into this whole HTML 5 thing, and this tutorial (http://www.webreference.com/authoring/languages/html/HTML5/) says  that these tags should move the content around without any kind of CSS at all, but all I'm getting is a line of text that looks like this:

```
 Header tag   Nav tag    Artical Section tags    Aside tag   footer tag
```

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>HTML5 test1</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    </head>

    <body> 
        <header>
            Header tag
        </header> 

        <nav>
            Nav tag
        </nav> 

        <article> 
            <section> 
                Artical Section tags
            </section> 
        </article>

        <aside>
            Aside tag
        </aside> 

        <footer>
            footer tag
        </footer> 
    </body>  
</html>
```

Comment: It's coming in Firefox 4, though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Firefox 3.6 doesn't support HTML 5 sectioning elements yet. You will have to manually style the tags to be block level:

```
article, aside, canvas, details,
figcaption, figure, footer, header,
hgroup, nav, section, summary, video {
    display: block;
}
```

You won't need the HTML shim, however; that's just for IE.

Comment: Make that "doesn't support HTML5 sectioning elements yet", with a specification as big as HTML5, "supporting HTML5" doesn't really mean much.

Comment: Just to say thanks. this was tripping me up and Google didn't seem to have the answer. For what it's worth (in case anyone else find this page) the same issue and solution also applies to Opera.

Answer (score 2):

These tags don’t work at all in Firefox 3.6.11 and Opera 11.0 — regardless of the CSS `display` property, they simply don’t parse correctly. For example, if you insert paragraph tags in the above example, it falls apart. [Here’s an example](http://jsfiddle.net/xF347/). You get the correct result in WebKit, Firefox 4, and Opera 11.11:

[image: WebKit screenshot]

But you get this in Opera 11.0 and Firefox 3.6:

[image: Opera screenshot]

Comment: Sure, but I shouldn’t have to change my markup to accomodate a broken parser.

Comment: Conversely: Firefox shouldn't change their parser for broken (invalid) html.

Not closing tags like <p> and <li> is technically invalid and will fail in the online validator.

Comment: FTR: not closing tags like <p> and <li> is most certainly valid. HTML does not have to be well-formed XML at all. This isn't new in HTML5; it's the way it's always been that some elements can created implicitly, and some closed implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to test the HTML5 output in Firefox (I can't imagine why) you could activate it through "about:config" and setting html5.enable to true. Remember that they didn't switch it off for nothing. 
For real world work you will need CSS, so I suggest you get stuck in with that as well.