# Any way to make firefox 3 compatible with HTML5 tags? (like section, header, etc.)

Tags: html, firefox-3

So yeah.. firefox 3 isn't compatible with html5 tags. How would one get around this without recoding everything? You know, like IE's conditional statement or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you need do is add 'display:block' to their CSS. Otherwise, FF works just fine with HTML5.

Comment: I can't confirm this (with Firefox 3.6.11) — see [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031020/html5-tags-not-working-at-all-in-firefox-3-6-3/4475368#4475368).

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do some basic browser detection. There's two ways of going about it: testing if a particular feature is available, or doing some analysis of the browser's ID string.

Check out http://www.html5test.com/ and analyze their JS/html code for ideas.

Comment: how do I go about running that test? (for features)

Comment: `el = document.createElement('somehtml5specifictag');`. If el's null, then that tag isn't supported and you can do something else in your scripts/css.