# Why FIrefox doesn't recognize <section>?

Tags: html, firefox, browser, cross-browser, firefox3.6

I would just like to confirm if Firefox can't interpret `<section>` tag? I created a website and tested it on Chrome and Safari. Everything was fine until I tested it on firefox and it was horrible. It took me almost 2 days just to figure out that Firefox cant handle `<section>` tag. I would just like to confirm because I am not sure about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding `article { display: block; }` to your style sheet. FF is probably treating it as an inline element because it's not fully supported.

I've used HTML5 to build a test system and it's worked fine on all browsers with a few tweaks.

**EDIT**

This is a script I wrote to test out some web scraping : http://randomcoding.com/steam/ I used HTML5 as the markup to see what all the fuss was about.

As you can see from the [stylesheet](http://randomcoding.com/steam/css/style.css), I've made some elements block items

```
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
```

This method works for me on most browsers I checked (Chrome, Opera 10, FF3-4, IE8-9).

However, if you're starting out, I recommend you have a look at HTML5 Boilerplate : http://html5boilerplate.com/

It's got the best practices for when using HTML5 to markup your site. A good place to start.

Comment: Thanks bro... I am kinda new to web development and I'm just on the process of learning. Could you please tell me how to make my css style compatible with all browsers.

Comment: Thanks bro... At least you gave me an idea.

Comment: doh! that's what I get for scanning instead of actually reading

Answer (score 2):

Take a read at [HTML5 tags not working at all in firefox 3.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031020/html5-tags-not-working-at-all-in-firefox-3-6-3)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has no problem with the `<section>` tag, but Internet Explorer has.