# jQuery each() not working for Firefox, working in webkit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which detects the section of a single-page site the user is currently on and, depending on the variable passed to it, scrolls to the next section or the previous. This is working fine in Safari and Chrome. However, in Firefox, regardless of where the scroll position is, it treats the browser as if it's at scroll 0.

```
function scrollToSection(dir) {
    if( !$("body").hasClass("scrolling") ) {
        $("body").addClass("scrolling");

        var headerH = $(".page-header").outerHeight();
        var scrollTop = $("body").scrollTop();

        $("section").each(function() {
            var sectionH = $(this).outerHeight(true);
            var sectionOffset = $(this).offset();
            var sectionOffsetTop = sectionOffset.top - headerH;
            if( (sectionOffsetTop <= scrollTop) && (sectionOffsetTop + sectionH >= scrollTop) ) {
                var prevSection = $(this).prev();
                var nextSection = $(this).next();
                if( dir === "up" ) {
                    $.scrollTo( prevSection, {
                            duration : 1000,
                            offset : {
                                top : -50
                            },
                            onAfter: function() {
                                $("body").removeClass("scrolling");
                            }

                        });
                } else {
                    $.scrollTo( nextSection, {
                            duration : 1000,
                            offset : {
                                top : -50
                            },
                            onAfter: function() {
                                $("body").removeClass("scrolling");
                            }
                        });
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469355/why-firefox-doesnt-recognize-section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FireFox needs the scrolltop set and read from the html element.
Other browsers store this on the body element.

do:

```
var scrollTop = $("html,body").scrollTop();
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realise Firefox cannot take scrollTop from the body.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
$("body").scrollTop();
```

Try using:

```
$("body,html").scrollTop();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change $('body') in $('body,html') . It should work